# Round number to specified precision in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, double, precision, rounding

I am trying to round a number to a specified precision using the half round up method of rounding. (i.e. 0.5 would be 1 rounding to one's precision). I tried the following of another SO question, however it fails to round properly:

```
//where x is number and precision is precision
int num = floor(log10(abs(x))) - precision + 1;
double temp = pow(10, num);
return floor(x / temp + 0.5) * temp;
```

Example: 2.55 rounds to 2.5 whereas I need it to round to 2.6

I was wondering if anyone had a better method of rounding a number to a given precision. I have already tried modifying this method without success.

Comment: *"it fails to round properly"* - What numbers did you test it with, what output do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: Doesn't `round` already do what you want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `NSDecimalNumber` for greater precision. See [`NSRoundingMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSDecimalNumberBehaviors_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000181-SW2) for the different rounding modes (I think you want `NSRoundPlain`)

```
NSDecimalNumberHandler *rounder = [NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:NSRoundPlain scale:precision raiseOnExactness:NO raiseOnOverflow:NO raiseOnUnderflow:NO raiseOnDivideByZero:NO];

NSDecimalNumber *number;
NSDecimaNumber *rounded = [number decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:rounder];
```

See the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumberHandler_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDecimalNumberHandler/decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:scale:raiseOnExactness:raiseOnOverflow:raiseOnUnderflow:raiseOnDivideByZero:) for more info on the `BOOL` parameters in the handler.

It might seem like a bit of an overkill for what you want but it ensures your numbers will rarely lose precision.

Change the [`scale`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSDecimalNumberBehaviors_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000181-CJBECJGD) argument of the `rounder` for more digits on the result (i.e. your `precision` variable).

Comment: I updated the questions `scale` argument to match the request in the update of your question.

Comment: Also to add `number` is left unassigned as I don't know how you currently get your number (is it from a `NSString`, `NSNumber`, etc.), but let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: After reading what [*half round up*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_up) is, I've changed it to `NSRoundPlain` which I think is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
-(double)roundNumber:(double)num toPrecision:(int)precision {

    double exact = num * pow(10, precision);
    double floor = floorl(exact);

    if ((floor + 1) <= (exact + 0.50)) {
        return (double) ((floor + 1) / pow(10, precision));
    }

    else
    {
        return (double) (floor / pow(10, precision));
    }

}
```

Where precision is the following: 2.1, rounding to .1 would be 1 precision. Rounding to 2 would be 0 precision. 
For something like 12.4, -1 precision would be 10. This is extremely reliable and I have not found any bugs in it.